# Create a timetable with HTML - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, schedule

I want to make a timetable in a HTML-table. I have a database structure set up and now I have trouble with displaying the database data in the HTML-table correctly.

My database structure involves:

[image]

The days are numbered by day_nr where 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday, 3 = wednesday, 4 = thursday and 5 = friday.
The hours are numbered by hour_nr from 1 to 10.

Here is an example of what I eventually want to create.

[image: CLICK ME FOR IMAGE]]

Some code:

```
<?php
session_start();
    // Connect MySQL Database
    require("function.php");
    $con = sql_connection();
        // Select data from database (select the right table)
    $result01 = mysqli_query("SELECT teacher_code, day_nr, hour_nr, subject_code, room_nr, class_code FROM `lesson`");

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered student_table'>
            <thead class='thead-inverse'> 
                <tr>
                    <th class='start_time'></th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>";
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you wrote so far?

Comment: So far I have a database connection and the beginning of the table. I've tried to get the data in the HTML-table a lot of ways, but I haven't succeeded so far.

Comment: Please provide some code, so that we can help

Comment: I've posted the code from the file I'm tring to make the table in. The functions.php is used to connect to the database and that works fine. As I said before, I've tried a lot but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Can you state that in the form of a question?

Comment: How can I put my database data sorted with day_nr and hour_nr in a HTML-table(shown in the picture)?

Comment: Can you please show me your database table.

Comment: @jyotimishra I added a picture of my database structure in the post.

Comment: for each start time there will be only one details respectve of days?

Comment: @jyotimishra the data should be displayed in the HTML-table sorted by hours (up to down) and days (left to right).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a data structure in your php program representing your time table.

Perhaps you should create an array with an element for each day. Each element of that top level array can itself contain an array, with an element for each time slot in the day.

Then each time slot element can contain an array, with an element for each item to represent in the time slot.

You can then populate this data structure as you retrieve your MySQL result set. You can then render it -- write it to HTML -- using PHP code.

Explaining how to create and use of data structure is, in my opinion, beyond the scope of what you should expect in a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have just echoed your table. now you need to echo the actual element in your database for that:
you might consider this

```
if($num = mysqli_num_rows($result01) > 1){
while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc[$result01]){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $res['name of your attribute in the database'];
    echo "</td><td></tr>";
}
```

}